# Zend Jquery Ajax posting object literals to PHP and parsing them

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, zend-framework

I have a very complex Jquery object that resembles a multidimensional array. Here is what it looks like using console.log

> [
>
> [] id [
>   "91900"
>   ]
>   location
>   [
>   "F43"
>   , 
>   "F44"
>   ]
>   prev_location
>   [
>   "F41"
>   ]
>   ,
>
> []
>   id
>   [
>   "92305"
>   ]
>   location
>   [
>   "F38"
>   , 
>   "F39"
>   ]
>   prev_location
>   [
>   "F39"
>   ]
>   ,
>
> []
>   id
>   [
>   "155972"
>   ]
>   location
>   [
>   "F35"
>   ]
>   prev_location
>   [
>   "F45"
>   ]
>
> ]

Trying to send that to a Zend controller using JQUERY/AJAX, I do try to stringify it but it comes as just Array when I post it on controller.

> data = JSON.stringify(big_array)
>
> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>           type: 'POST',
>             dataType: 'json', 
>             url: '/project/public/index/send', 
>             async: false,
>             data: {myJson:  data},
>             success: function(response) {
>             }
>             });
> ```

Below is the controller, trying to output something so firebug can show me on HTML response at least something but nothing but Array shows up

> public function sendAction() {
>
> ```
>   $data = $this->_request->getPost();
>     $data_array = json_decode($data['myJson'], true);
>     print_r($data_array);
> }
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your data is not easily expressible as valid JSON. I would recommend keeping your datatype as html or text then processing it into JSON (or whatever format you need) in php.

```
data = big_array;

$.ajax({

      type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text', 
        url: '/project/public/index/send', 
        async: false,
        data: data,
           success: function(response) {
        }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use something like this: http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/ to encode the chunks of the array before you JSON-ify the data. But, then you would need to decode the chunks on the server anyway.

Hope this helps.

P.S. I am curious as to why you are using async: false?

Comment: I did try as HTML and TXT but still wasn't able to get the data, seems like the data is too complex. I did end up parsing it a different way and sending it out as elements so could add that as answer. Async I read on Jquery page this, so probably messed my logic up: Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation

Comment: You probably don't want to use async:false - it blocks all user interaction (and scripts) until the ajax request completes.